# Implementing automatic event based reminder in Web API project?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I am doing a Social media app for employees with in an organisation, In that notification based on certain events have to be fired at corresponding dates such as anniversary, birthday etc. i was searching a way to implement that concept.Its actually Web API project, android and ios devices raises API call in order to update these things for UI.

The database is SQL Server. I need  a dynamic update for employee birthday, farewell etc.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to poll the database with a running service that would then call into your API or you could use something like SignalR for real-time data syncing. WebAPI on it's own won't do what you need because it is a request/response model.

Comment: for that purpose can i use services? Can you provide me detailed solution or usefull link for that